# Guidelines for building web pages specifically for iPhone and iPod touch

Tags: iphone

I need to build a couple of pages that will only be ever viewed from either an iPhone or an iTouch.

Are there guidelines or tutorials for building such pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking out the [Design4Mobile](http://patterns.design4mobile.com/index.php/Main_Page) wiki.

Answer (score 1):

This is the starting point you want:

http://developer.apple.com/safari/

If you are targeting only those platforms, you have a greatly expanded set of abilities you can take advantage of.

Also, there is a WWDC video or two covering exactly this - those are a little expensive though (you have to buy the whole set for around $300 I believe).  You want sessions 201, 202, 204 and 206 which are all related to web development on the iPhone.  You can learn more about that here:

http://developer.apple.com/products/videos.html